# SWIG - float array in struct to c# - SWIGTYPE_p_float

Tags: c#, struct, swig

I have an question. I'm trying to use swig to wrap some native dll, which contains struct looking like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    float y[const1];
    float z[const2];
} MyStruct;
```

and c# representation for y and z is not an array, but SWIGTYPE_p_float. Is there way to tell swig to interpret my float y[const1] as an array, and not SWIGTYPE_p_float? I have already tried "memberin" and "typemap", with no success. Thanx in advanced...

Comment: Show a *full* example inluding C# code. Otherwise this looks like a C/C++ question.

Comment: Tell us about `const1` and `const2`, by making a minimal complete example. Otherwise it's impossible to give you a real answer here, they could be lots of things.

Comment: @ceno Did you get any solutions? If so, can you share? (Cai in the same problem, 3 years after you)